# Google Data API - Trying to exchange an authsub_token for a session_token via upgradetosessiontoken results in "NonAuthSubToken"

Tags: python, google-api-client

I'm using exactly the code in the examples from here: http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#Auth

Still no dice.

Here is the exact code I've got (this is all running on a web server):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media
import gdata.geo

print "content-type:text/html\n"

def GetAuthSubUrl():
  next = 'http://my_domain.com/foo/connect_picasa.cgi'
  scope = 'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/'
  secure = False
  session = True
  gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
  return gd_client.GenerateAuthSubURL(next, scope, secure, session);

authSubUrl = GetAuthSubUrl();
print '<a href="%s">Login to your Google account</a>' % authSubUrl
```

And then at `my_domain/foo/connect_picasa.cgi` I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media
import gdata.geo
import cgi

parameters = cgi.FieldStorage()
authsub_token = parameters['token']

print "content-type:text/html\n"

#debugging
print authsub_token

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
gd_client.auth_token = authsub_token
gd_client.UpgradeToSessionToken()

#more debugging
print "BLINKENLICHTEN"
```

It's bailing out at `gd_client.UpgradeToSessionToken()` with: `raise NonAuthSubToken`

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?  Doing `parameters['token']` and `parameters['token'].value` [which seems more obvious to me] result in the same thing.  Setting the authsub_token to "tacos", also results in the same error, leading me to believe that my authsub_token in simply invalid.

Comment: Even though you've already figured this out, I strongly recommend using OAuth 2 instead of AuthSub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question so that others can benefit from it:

The google documentation is out of date.  Found the answer here: http://www.mail-archive.com/google-calendar-help-dataapi@googlegroups.com/msg09180.html

This is what the code should look like:

It *does* need the actual value.  So either give it a .value, or use parameters.getvalue("token")

```
authsub_token = parameters['token'].value
print "content-type:text/html\n"

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
```

This is the important part.  Use gd_client.SetAUthSubToken, not gd_client.authsubtoken =

```
gd_client.SetAuthSubToken(authsub_token) 
gd_client.UpgradeToSessionToken()
```

Hope this helps anybody else out.  This was a real headbanger.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a ton. Now, how do I save the session token so I don't have to re-authorize my app each time I use it?

Comment: Thanks you, Ryan! Much better tutorial, then Google documentation;)